# Solr UI Authentication required in Kerberized environment

Tags: hadoop, solr, kerberos, ambari

I am working on a kerberized HDP cluster, in which I have infra Solr instance in 3 nodes.
When I try to connect to solr UI I get this error :

```
Kerberos Authentication

    Your browser did not provide the required information to authenticate using Kerberos. Please check that your computer has a valid ticket for communicating with Solr, and that your browser is properly configured to provide that ticket when required. For more information, consult Solr's Kerberos documentation .
    The response from the server was:

    HTTP 401 Authentication required
    WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
```

In the instance server, I can easily curl to the Solr URL using a ticket for it.
I tried the browser configuration mentioned in the [Cloudera docs (for mozilla)](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/authentication-with-kerberos/content/authe_spnego_enabling_browser_access_to_a_spnego_enabled_web_ui.html),
but it's not working.

Anyone had or know how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve this issue, in fact I needed to add this lines in the Advanced topology Knox ( in ambari ui ):

```
<service> <role>SOLR</role> 
                     <url>http://<hostname1>:8886/solr/</url>
                     <url>http://<hostname2>:8886/solr/</url>
                     <url>http://<hostname3>:8886/solr/</url>
     </service>
```

and then I added the SOLR service in the : `gateway.dispatch.whitelist.services` in Advanced gateway-site